# How to square a number that got more digits than search results "digits" on Google.

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I am [implementing](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/quadratic-sieve) the [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) algorithm. And I got run in unexpected problem.

Take a look at those two final steps of the algorithm as described in wiki.

> 4. Use linear algebra to find a subset of these vectors which add to the zero vector. Multiply the corresponding $a_i$ together naming the
>      result mod $n$: a and the $b_i$ together which yields a B-smooth square $b^2$.
> 5. We are now left with the equality $a^2=b^2$ mod $n$ from which we get two square roots of ($a^2$ mod $n$), one by taking the square root in the
>      integers of $b^2$ namely $b$, and the other the $a$ computed in step 4.

In my case I found more than $100$ vectors with the size of $30+$ digits each, when multiplying them I get a number that got too many digits, so squaring it becomes a problem, it takes more time than solving the matrix itself(I use the [babylon method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) for squaring).

Is there a way to avoid creating such big numbers?

Comment: The Babylon method you link to is for calculating square roots, while your question deals with squaring.

Comment: @RossMillikan In order to solve $a^2 \equiv b^2$ mod $N$ I need to use square root

Comment: You can do all multipllications modulo the number you want to factor.

Comment: @Peter this is exactly what I am after. I don't understand why this should work? If I found a square, why should it be square after I do module the number that I am factoring?

Comment: If $a^2=b^2$ modulo $n$ , then $a'^2=b'^2$ modulo $n$, if $a'=a$ modulo $n$ and $b'=b$ modulo $n$.